# Android source code download corrupt?

Tags: android

I have a problem regarding Android source code download.
I have downloaded Android source code from Google and it says that the source code is 8.5 GB size. But from my estimates, I must have downloaded only around 2-3 GB size (roughly).
The directory where I downloaded source code is showing size of 15 GB! and doing repo sync shows that download is complete.

Here is some more information:
I downloaded using the command
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

What did I do wrong? There were times when during the download, I paused using ctrl z and resumed with fg. Also sometimes the net disconnected and I had to do repo sync again. Could that have corrupted the download? How do I check whether my download is ok?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a problem with the source other than sizes that don't match your expectations? repo / git are based on file hashes and won't go easily corrupt.

Comment: No other problem. I am just confused by source code size variations as mentioned above i.e. how did my 2-3 GB download become 15 GB and google talks about 8.5 GB?

Comment: repo does a lot of symlink magic so it could be that it appears larger - downloading could be using compression which works pretty good with text files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Git repository a very **very** unlikely to have corrupted files, because it checks them. 
So like @zapl said, if that's your sole "problem" then you don't have one.

Git downloaded repositories' sizes has nothing to do with the final disk space used by the source.

As a good practice, Git compresses files and use "deltas" and other objects to build the files locally: **So the files are not transfered in a binary way**.

Comment: Thank you and zapl for your enlightening answers